# Queries about Confidence Level and Linked Id in the api response

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

1.How confidence level is scaled ? As it ranges from 0 to 1 but What it means when it its value is 0.0, <0.5, >0.5, 1?Is there any document or reference for the same?

2.Is Linked Id is unique for the road(for specific region or for all region)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 2:

Yes link IDs are permanent and unique across all regions.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-route-link.html

Question 1:

Confidence level here is a coefficient: `0.0` to `1.0` which corresponds to `0` to `100%`.
The meaning is the same: indicates how certain an algorithm is about the accuracy of its results.